# Bootstrap tabs not working while generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the following [bootstrap tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) in my website, generated dynamically from ajax requests.

While i was trying the static version of those tabs all was working perfectly but now when i'm generating all tabs and pane dynamically when i press on the tab it just doesn't set the show attribute to it's pane..

As the content is added dynamically the on click is made of `.on('click', 'a'..)`

Here is the code snippet...

I just cant find what i'm generating wrong as the dynamic code is equals to static one..

```js
$('#tab').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-scroller py-1 pb-1 mb-2">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs d-flex justify-content-between" id="tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu active" id="4-men" href="#4-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="4-tab" aria-selected="true" data-id="4">RINFESCHI</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="12-men" href="#12-tab" data-toggle="tab"
      role="tab" aria-controls="12-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="12">PRALINERIA</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="13-men" href="#13-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="13-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="13">CONFEZIONI</a>
    <a
      class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="14-men" href="#14-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="14-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="14">MENU 010</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="15-men" href="#15-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="15-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="15">STAGIONALI</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="17-men" href="#17-tab"
        data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="17-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="17">ACCONTO </a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="18-men" href="#18-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="18-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="18">INGROSSO</a>
      <a
        class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="19-men" href="#19-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="19-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="19">VINI</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="20-men" href="#20-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="20-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="20">CAFFETTERIA</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="4-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="4-men">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">PIZZE </h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€20,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">902</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€2,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">903</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€3,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">TORTE SALATE</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€20,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">904</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€4,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">905</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€5,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">PANETTONE GASTRONOMICO</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€20,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">906</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€6,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">907</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€7,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">FINGER FOOD</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€1,50</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">901</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€1,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="12-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="12-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="13-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="13-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="14-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="14-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="15-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="15-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="17-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="17-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="18-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="18-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="19-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="19-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="20-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="20-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure on the cause. I suspect it is because the bootstrap event handlers are not being attached as you stated that the tabs are generated using ajax requests.

I played with the javascript in your example and got the tabs to change. Hope this helps.

```js
$('#tab').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  dataId = $(this).data('id');
  $("[id$='-tab']").hide();
  $('#'+dataId+'-tab').show();
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-scroller py-1 pb-1 mb-2">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs d-flex justify-content-between" id="tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu active" id="4-men" href="#4-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="4-tab" aria-selected="true" data-id="4">RINFESCHI</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="12-men" href="#12-tab" data-toggle="tab"
      role="tab" aria-controls="12-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="12">PRALINERIA</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="13-men" href="#13-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="13-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="13">CONFEZIONI</a>
    <a
      class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="14-men" href="#14-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="14-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="14">MENU 010</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="15-men" href="#15-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="15-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="15">STAGIONALI</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="17-men" href="#17-tab"
        data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="17-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="17">ACCONTO </a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="18-men" href="#18-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="18-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="18">INGROSSO</a>
      <a
        class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="19-men" href="#19-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="19-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="19">VINI</a><a class="nav-item p-2 text-muted menu" id="20-men" href="#20-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="20-tab" aria-selected="false" data-id="20">CAFFETTERIA</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="4-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="4-men">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">PIZZE </h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€20,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">902</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€2,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">903</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€3,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">TORTE SALATE</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€20,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">904</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€4,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">905</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€5,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">PANETTONE GASTRONOMICO</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€20,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">906</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€6,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">907</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€7,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">FINGER FOOD</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€1,50</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid d-none" src="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-0">901</h3>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <h2 class="text-right text-success price">€1,00</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="12-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="12-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="13-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="13-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="14-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="14-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="15-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="15-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="17-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="17-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="18-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="18-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="19-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="19-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="20-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="20-men">
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was going for that solution too.. but actually the event handler is attached as in debug the `$(this).tab('show')` is reached.. as you can see here https://i.gyazo.com/7d63abd9fd54c0cf98f35996dbb279dc.mp4 when one of tab is pressed the click is handled and even the state of aria-selected is changed..